# Chatbot on iphone - Resources/apps/service to provide front-end?

Tags: java, iphone, chat, chatbot, smartphone

I'm currently trying to make an app (or web-based program) which is a chatbot.

Is any open-source code or an app or a service that would allow me to just focus on the back end of the program so that I only need to handle the input from the user and produce an output as a response in the chat?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of frameworks at various stages of functionality and maturity.

- https://github.com/little2s/NoChat
- https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-iOS
- https://layer.com/

Pick one.